# Google AdWord Example to haml

Tags: haml, google-ads-api

Given this example:  https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3207306?hl=en&rd=1

How would I convert the code listed under the "Troubleshooting your code snippet" section to haml?

The closest I've come is:

```
%script{:type=>"text/javascript"}
  :cdata
    var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "3";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    var google_conversion_value = 0;
    var google_remarketing_only = false;
%script{:type => "text/javascript", :src => "//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"}
%noscript
  %div{:style => "display:inline;"}
    %img{:height => "1", :width => "1", :style => "border-style:none;", :alt => "", :src => "//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/123456789/?value=0&amp;label= AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0".html_safe}
```

The problem with above is the `:cdata` tag produces:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
        var google_conversion_language = "en";
        var google_conversion_format = "3";
        var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
        var google_conversion_label = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
        var google_conversion_value = 0;
        var google_remarketing_only = false;

    ]]>
</script>
```

And not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   /* <![CDATA[ */
   var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
   var google_conversion_language = "en";
   var google_conversion_format = "2";
   var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
   var google_conversion_label = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
   var google_conversion_value = 0;
   /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Is there a way to explicitly declare the `CDATA` tag?  Or is Google not that picky about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape / in haml with a \ at the beginning of the line.  I had the same issue and the following worked for me to include the google adwords conversion tracking code in our site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
\/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "2";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
\/* ]]> */
</script>
```

which after haml processing turns into:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "2";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

After haggling with many variations of the above, I finally "cheated" and just used the :plain tag to get it exactly the way I wanted.  The code below exactly replicates what was on the Google Analytics example page, and the Google Tag Assistant plugin for Chrome confirms that it's coming through properly.  Note: I also had to change the googleadservices link to HTTPS so that it would match the rest of my page (that was causing other problems that were hard to chase down, and Tag Assistant helped to sort it out).

This should do it for you:

```
%script{:type=>"text/javascript"}
  :plain
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "3";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    var google_conversion_value = 0;
    var google_remarketing_only = false;
    /* ]]> */
%script{:type => "text/javascript", :src => "https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CDATA` tag isn’t really needed in HTML. The intention is that it allows the use of things like literal `<` in the javascript without having to escape them. `CDATA` sections are sometimes used with XHTML, but even then XHTML is usually treated as HTML by the browser.

With Haml, you could use the [`:javascript` filter](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#javascript-filter) for blocks like this. That will add the `CDATA` section if your document format is XHTML, and leave it out otherwise. It will also omit the `type` attribute if the format is HTML5, since the default is `text/javascript` in that case.

So:

```haml
:javascript
  var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
  // etc ...
```

Will produce this when the format is HTML5 (the default)

```html
<script>
  var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
  // etc ...
</script>
```

and this when the format is XHTML:

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
    var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
    // etc ...
  //]]>
</script>
```

Note that this uses `//` comments for the `CDATA` markers rather than `/* ... */` that the Google page suggests, but this shouldn’t matter.

Comment: According to Google, the `CDATA` tag is required to get this to work properly.  Additionally the script tag must explicitly be set to `<script type='text/javascript'>` - major bummer.  For now, I'm implementing the call simply using the tracking pixel, but I'd love to get the JS working.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @CDub I suspect Google is just being a bit conservative about their instructions on that page – the javascript should run in the browser without `CDATA` sections or the `type` attribute. If you want to be really sure of what you’re generating you could use the [`:plain` filter](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#plain-filter) and include the javascript block verbatim.